# Mysql data processing in Spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where I need to fetch data every 5 minute from multiple source systems (Mysql instances) and join and enrich them with some other data(present in S3 lets say).

I wanted to this processing in Spark to distribute my execution across multiple executors.

The main problem is everytime I do a lookup in Mysql, I only want to fetch latest records (lets say with lastModifiedOn > timestamp).
How can this selective fetch of MySql rows happen effectively?
This is what I have tried:

```
val filmDf = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sakila")
  .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "film").option("user", "root").option("password", "")
  .load()
```

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have tried ?

Comment: @eliasah Yes will update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use spark sql with jdbc datasource. I show you an example.

```
val res = spark.read.jdbc(
      url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=minty&password=greatsqldb",
      table = "TEST.table",
      columnName = "lastModifiedOn",
      lowerBound = lowerTimestamp,
      upperBound = upperTimestamp,
      numPartitions = 20,
      connectionProperties = new Properties()
    )
```

There are more examples in Apache Spark test suite: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JDBCSuite.scala

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what do we mean by numPartitions here?
And connectionProperties as well?

Comment: The result will be a DataFrame with numPartitions partitions. Spark will execute numPartitions queries in parallel to retrieve results. Example: 
lowerBound=1, upperBound=10, numPartitions=2,  Spark will execute two queries, first one between 1 and 5 and second one between 6 and 10.

Comment: connectionProperties is a Map to pass some properties to the db. Depends on your db you can use it or not.